# App ID with Identifier is not available. Please enter a different string

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-id

I developed an app, using the identifier it.xxx.yyy. At the time, I was not enrolled to the Developer Program, and I used an *old_account*.

Now I've enrolled to the program with a *new_account* (apple id). When I try to export the archive e validate it, I get the error *"App ID with Identifier is not available"*

I guess its' because I've already used it with my *old_account* (not enrolled and then never uploaded to the store). Anyway, that AppId was not listed among the identifiers of the *old_account*

What should I do to be able to use the same AppID?  I've already  tried to delete all the profiles..
thank you

===UPDATE

I've just noticed that within Xcode, under the old_account, among the provisioning profiles there is the one I'd like to use with the new_user. Strange thing, is that it's available for download, but on the portal it's not present. Where does Xcode get it? How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Please go through https://developer.apple.com/  and add a app ID in your account with same bundle identifier.
2. Create provisional certificate using this AppId.
3. Go to Xcode Project --> Target --> add your team here.
4. Go to Xcode --> Preferences --> Acount --> Add your account here.

Hope your problem will be resolved.

Thanks

Enjoy Coding.

Comment: remove invalid iOS team provision profile managed by Xcode from developer portal.   Create new one and download it.

Comment: deleted all from the porta.... I deleted profiles and certificate. Still getting the same error "appId not available". I tried to add the app to iTunes Connect, and it says that the AppId is already used (probably by my old_account). How can I dissociate it from that?

Comment: I've just noticed that within Xcode, under the old_account, among the provisioning profiles there is the one I'd like to use with the new_user. Strange thing, is that it's available for download, but on the portal it's not present. Where does Xcode get it? How can I get rid of it?